# Modify Gradle build file to watch a non-source file for changes and trigger compile

Tags: gradle

I have a non-source configuration file that affects how my project is built. If I change that file and run Gradle (when the source files haven't changed), then it doesn't recompile at all. What can I do in my build file that will make Gradle treat changes to that config file as if they were changes to source files?

More simply, perhaps, how do I get Gradle to watch a particular (non-source) file so that changes to that file trigger an out-of-date compilation to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add files as task inputs via the methods [`file(Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#file-java.lang.Object-), [`files(Object...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#files-java.lang.Object...-) and [`dir(Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#dir-java.lang.Object-) of the [`TaskInputs`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html) object of any task (accessible via `task.inputs`).

Just decide which task is the first one to depend on the file(s) as input(s).